# navigation in ng-grid(also between two ng-grid) using tab key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

In my project I am using ng-grid. My requirement is to navigate between grid cells using tab key which is possible using enableCellSelection :true. also to make a cell editable I am using enableCellEdit: true.

But there are some issue I am facing right now

1.when editing in textarea/textbox its size is changing(textbox height change to the height of cell selection)

2.Unable to navigate between two grids present in same page using tab key.

3.Sometimes tab key is not working properly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can setup tab navigation inside the Grid by turning noTabInterference flag on in gridOptions (exmple: gridIotion.noTabInterference = true)

Answer (score 0):

to 1.) you can write your own template for textarea/input cells and add it to gridOptions:

```
 $scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{field: 'somefield', displayName: 'Some Field', cellTemplate: 'yourTemplateHere'}
 };
```

some template examples [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating)

if you have styling issues you can also overwrite editableCellTemplate and set its height to what you need.

you could also overwrite ng-grids default templates: [github link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/tree/master/src/templates)

to 2.) you may have to set your own [tabindex](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) and increment it dynamically using $index and col.colIndex().

example for cellTemplate:

```
<div class="ngCellText" tabindex="(($index + 1) * 10) + col.colIndex()" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</span></div>
```

(($index + 1) * 10) + col.colIndex() will resolve in:

10 11 12 13

20 21 22 23

30 31 32 33

etc.

// sorry, not sure how to format this. did you get what i try to visualize?

to 3.) not sure to help you with 'not working proberly' ;) any more info? in which situations?

Comment: I am using cellTemplate, added two screenshot for your reference

Comment: Also I need little clarity for the solution you have provided for my 2nd question. About my 3rd question : Tab is not moving to the 2nd cell when focus enters into the grid. I have to manually click on the first cell, there after everything works fine.

Comment: This plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/cCcuBqd7RuZ0SHvz4BZp?p=preview has some resemblance with my problem. just add two properties to gridOptions : enableCellEdit: true,
    enableCellSelection: true. First click on the first textbox and then press tab, cell selection moved to first cell,and tab works no more unless you press arrow keys. Every time you click on textbox and then press tab there is inconsistent movement.